# Simple instance_variable_set in RSpec does not work, but why not?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am kind of lost in a simple task in testing a Ruby app using RSpec:

```
class Script
  # content does not matter
  def initialize
  end

  def my_timezone_description(timeZoneId)
    @timeZonesCache[timeZoneId]
  end
end
```

Specs:

```
  it 'gets the timezone description' do
    Script.instance_variable_set(:@timeZonesCache, {123 => '+01:00'} )
    expect(Script.new.my_timezone_description(123)).to eq '+01:00'
  end
```

`Script.instance_variable_get(:@timeZonesCache)` gives me back the correct hash.

Can someone explain why this is not working and how I can get it to work?

Comment: Hint: `instance_variable_set` sets a variable on an instance. What instance are you calling it on? What instance are you reading the instance variable back from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `#instance_variable_set` on `Script` instance, not on the class itself:

```
  it 'gets the timezone description' do
    script = Script.new
    script.instance_variable_set(:@timeZonesCache, ({123 => '+01:00'}) )
    expect(script.my_timezone_description(123)).to eq '+01:00'
  end
```

Otherwise you set instance variable for the class object, not for the instance object.

What you do now is a equivalent of

```
class Script
  @timeZonesCache = {123 => '+01:00'}
end
```